# Retrieving image stored in a network folder?

Tags: graphics, pdftex, texlive

I am trying to create a header for a TeX file that includes an image.  The image in question is located in the network directory "\\FileStore1\Forms\IT Info\Apps\pdfTex\images\", and I am having a terrible time getting the pdflatex.exe to not throw an error.

Attached is my code, any and all help is greatly appreciated.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage[space]{grffile}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\graphicspath{//FileStore1/Forms/IT Info/Apps/pdfTex/images}
%\graphicspath{{./../../images/}}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-.5in}
\setlength{\textheight}{8in}
\setlength{\headheight}{51.1pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\lhead{\includegraphics[keepaspectratio=true]{head.png}}
\rhead{Company Name\\
Street Address\\
City, State ZIP\\
phone number}
\lfoot{This is an auto-generated report}
blah blah blah\\
foo bar\\
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l c}
Key & Data\\
1 & 2
%<TableData>
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Edit 1: 
Following a suggestion from Mr. Oberdiek, I changed/added the following 2 lines

```
\usepackage{grffile}
\graphicspath{{\\FileStore1\Forms\IT Info\Apps\pdfTex\images\}}
```

Comment: `\usepackage{grffile}` + `\graphicspath{{.../}}` (each entry in `\graphicspath` is surrounded by curly braces, thus for one path you need two pairs. Also the path in `\graphicspath` should end with the directory separator.

Comment: I tried what you said.  I included `\usepackage{grffile}` and modified my `\graphicspath` (see new code at end of question), and there is still an error.

Comment: Use forward slases. Otherwise the backslash would be interpreted as start of a TeX macro.

Comment: That appears to fix the issue! Thanks a ton! Mind submitting an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `\usepackage{grffile}` adds support for the space.
- The path entries in `\graphicspath` are surrounded by braces. Thus if one path is used, two pair of braces are needed, e.g.: `\graphicspath{{images/}}`.
- The path entries in `\graphicspath` should end with the directory separator, because the `graphics` package makes a simple concatenation of the path and image name. It does not take care of directory separators, ...
- Backslashes are interpreted as start of TeX commands by TeX, thus forward slashes are used instead (Windows supports them except on the command line).

Summary:

```
\usepackage{grffile}% option space is the default for the supported drivers
\graphicspath{{//FileStore1/Forms/IT Info/Apps/pdfTex/images/}}
```